# Cannot click to SVG element with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

this is my full project code please guys run this code and help to me fix this problem
I have issue in my find_the_place_path() function also you need to add :
form_data.txt to you folder of project and inside of txt file should be
Myrat Durdyyew Erkek 26 08 1988 Pasport I-AG 266556
also you can download my project via link below and run code :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mlBshD2EHH1Y5k14iYpertF-P25_qCWy/view?usp=sharing

```
from ast import Return, Try
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
from codecs import getencoder
from distutils.command.sdist import sdist
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from operator import and_
from pickle import TRUE
from select import select
import time
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



class Project:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

    self.main()


def find_the_place_path(self):

  # firstly I will get the all path tags
  all_place_in_path = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("path")
  
  # title of my path tag is "gat: 3"
  for place in all_place_in_path:
    print(place.get_attribute('title'))
    if place.get_attribute('title') == "gat: 3":
      # this code don't worked for me  
      print("  Joined in to if  ")
      wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
      wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='path'][@title='gat: 3']"))).click()
      break


def find_the_place_rect(self ):

  all_place_in_rect = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("rect")

  for place in all_place_in_rect:
    print(place.get_attribute('title'))
    if place.get_attribute('title') == "gat: 1":
      self.driver.findElement(By.xpath ("//*[local-name()='svg' and @id='45']/*[localname()='path']"));
    if place.get_attribute('title') == "gat: 2":
      print("2 A girdim ")
      btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and @id='45']/*[localname()='path']")
      btn.click()
      break
    if place.get_attribute('title') == "gat: 3":
       print("3 E girdim")

def input_data(self):

  data=open("form_data.txt","r")
  for line in data:
    count = 0
    data.readline()[count]
    words=line.split()
    print(words)
    if words:
      first_name = words[0]
      last_name = words[1]
      gender = words[2]
      bday = words[3]
      bmoth = words[4]
      byear = words[5]
      document_type = words[6]
      document_snumber = words[7]
      document_number = words[8]
      count += 1

    time.sleep(3)
    phone = self.driver.find_element_by_id("phone").send_keys('61260799')
    print(phone)
       
    jyns = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("jyns"))
    jyns.select_by_visible_text(gender)
 
    client_last_name = self.driver.find_element_by_id('lastname').send_keys(last_name)

    client_name = self.driver.find_element_by_id('name').send_keys(first_name)

    buyer_mail = self.driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("welbekowallanur@gmail.com")

    # WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'passport')))
    
    passport = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("passport"))
    passport.select_by_visible_text(document_type)

    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'passport_code_b')))

    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.first > div.slide > div.info_r > div.wrap > ul > li > div > div.passport_code_b > div:nth-child(1)')
    pass_region = elements[0]


    passport_region = Select(pass_region.find_element_by_id("passport"))
    passport_region.select_by_visible_text(document_snumber)

    passport_code = self.driver.find_element_by_id('code').send_keys(document_number)

    day = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("bday"))
    day.select_by_visible_text(bday)

    month = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("bmonth"))
    month.select_by_visible_text(bmoth + " - Iýul")

    year = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("byear"))
    year.select_by_visible_text(byear)
    
    try:
      covid = self.driver.find_element_by_id("kepilnama").send_keys("321")
    except:
       print("Covid 19 NULL")
    
    time.sleep(3)
    choose_place_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[4]/div/button")
    choose_place_btn.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    self.find_the_place_path()

    #self.payment()


def main(self):

    self.driver.get("https://railway.gov.tm/")
    self.driver.maximize_window()

    select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("one_way"))
    self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('one_way').style.display = 'block';")
    from_where =  select.select_by_visible_text("Aşgabat")
    #self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('dropdown-content').setAttribute('style', 'display: block');")
  
    select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("two_way"))
    self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('two_way').style.display = 'block';")

    to_where = select.select_by_visible_text("Daşoguz")
    
    self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('search_date').setAttribute('data-value', '2022-08-09');")
    time.sleep(1)

    btn = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/a").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    #change_class = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div/ul/li/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li")
    #self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'seat_1')", change_class)
    self.check_ticken()

   
def check_ticken(self):
   
   li = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
   for l in li:
      print(l.get_attribute('class'))
      if l.get_attribute("class") == "seat_1                                            ":
        print("1 - nji")
        seat = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div/ul/li/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li").click()
        self.input_data()
        
      if l.get_attribute("class") == "seat_                                            ":
        print("2 - nji")
        self.main()
        self.driver.refresh()
                

def payment(self):

  card_number = "9931020202020202"
  card_holder = "ALLANUR WELBEKOW"
  cvc = "999"

  card_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pan_visible']").send_keys(card_number)
  d_month_select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("month"))
  d_month_selected = d_month_select.select_by_visible_text("Июль")

  d_year_select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("year"))
  d_year_selected =d_month_select.select_by_visible_text("2035")

  card_holder_fill = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='iTEXT']").send_keys(card_holder)
  cvc_fill = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='iCVC']").send_keys(cvc)


if __name__=="__main__":
    pr = Project()
```

Answer (score -2):

In find_the_place_path change xpath as shown in image
[image]